# Github / EGit pull request workflow

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

Say I have a repo and someone forks it. Then they do work and submit a pull request. But the code contains a large number of lines and/or it creates a GUI. I'd like to fetch it so I can actually see it run from Eclipse before merging it into my master. The options I've come up with are:

1. Create a second repo in EGit and clone directly from their fork.
2. Create a new branch just for them. Then leave a comment for the request asking them to re-submit the pull request using the new branch and that I'll be closing the current request (without merging)
3. Always keep around a branch for them to use in their pull requests.

Besides setting up an organization on Github what else could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then leave a comment for the request asking them to re-submit the pull request using the new branch and that I'll be closing the current request

They don't have to re-submit, it you test and merge first locally, as described in the "[Merging a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request)" GitHub page.

```
git checkout master
git pull https://github.com/otheruser/repo.git branchname
```

If the local merge works, then you can go ahead and merge the pull request through the GitHub web interface.

GitHub has documented how to [checkout a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally).
As I have illustrated before in "[What support for `git namespaces` exists in git hosting services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57320108/6309)", you can use `refs/pull/<PRNumber>/head` as remote pull reference, in command line or in Egit when, for instance, [creating a new branch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Branch_Creation_Dialog).

Comment: I'm using Egit not Git from the command line. But I see what you're saying. I created a new remote using the URL Github gave me and configured it for fetch. Then fetched, which created a tracking branch for it. Then I created a new local branch based on the tracking branch. Thank's VonC.

Answer (score 0):

If the PR number is 123, you can simply use the EGit Pull action, and use `pulls/123/head` as reference.