# What support for `git namespaces` exists in git hosting services

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

[Git Namespaces](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces) allow partitioning of single repositories and sharing. This can be useful as a basis for versioning.

Can someone provide me information what support the following platforms provide for this feature:

- Gitlab
- Github
- Bitbucket

My research did not provide any results.

Answer (score 0):

At least GitHub does use namespaces with **pull requests**

When you [import a PR in your repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), you would use the **pull namespace**.

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

But:

> The remote `refs/pull/` namespace is **read-only**.
>   If you try to push any commits there, you'll see this error:
>
> ```
> ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/pull/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.local:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git'
> ```

So I did not see any full (ie read/write) support.
And the [notion of "namespace"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#namespaces) for GitLab is completely different anyway.

Comment: I think this isn't the namespace facility he's referring to. `git help namespaces`.

Comment: @jthill I meant only to give an example of publicly exposed namespace, to contrast with the fact no `refs/namespaces/xxx` are exposed by those services.

Answer (score 0):

While the hosting providers mentioned may use Git namespaces internally, none of them document this as a feature for users. Namespaces are typically seen as a niche feature that is not commonly used, and people often misuse them for security purposes, which is not effective.

Hosting providers generally also want to encourage the use of more smaller repositories over single large repositories, since the former perform much better on both the client and the server side.

If you want a definitive answer, you'd have to inquire with those providers yourself.